# Problem 2, Chapter 2 from Herstein's book

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

I have encountered into challenging problem (it's my humble opinion) from Herstein's book. I have spent few hours in order to crack it and eventually I have done it after trying many approaches. So please check out my solution.

Let $G$ be a group such that the intersection of all its subgroup which are different from $\{e\}$ is a subgroup different from $\{e\}$. Prove that every element in $G$ has finite order.

**Proof:** Suppose that conclusion is not true $\Rightarrow$ $\exists a\in G$ such that $o(a)=\infty$ $\Rightarrow$ all elements in the set $\{a^0=e, a, a^2,a^3,\dots\}$ are distinct.

Denote by $\mathcal{A}=\{H\  \text{subgroups of} \ G: H\neq \{e\}\}$. Let's consider $K_n=\left \langle a^n \right \rangle$, and we know that $K_n$ is a subgroup of $G$  generated by $a^n$ and each $K_n$ are different from $\{e\}$. Hence for any $n\geqslant 1$ the following inclusion is true: $K_n\subset \mathcal{A}$.

We'll prove that $\bigcap \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}K_n=\{e\}$. Suppose it's not true then $\exists x\in K_n$ for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $x\neq e$.
Since $x\in K_1$ then $x=a^m$. Also $x\in K_2$ then $x=a^{2m_1}$ and since $o(a)=\infty$ then $2\mid m$. And continuing this process it follows that $n\mid m$ for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$ which is contradiction.

By the condition of problem we know that $\bigcap \limits_{H\in \mathcal{A}}H$ is different from $\{e\}$. So $\exists b\in G$ ($b\neq e$) such that $b\in H$ for any $H\in \mathcal {A}$ $\Rightarrow$ $b\in K_n$ for all $n\geqslant 1$ which contradiction.

The derived contradicition means that $\forall a\in G$ we have that $o(a)<\infty$.

Maybe above reasoning is too lengthy, but I guess that it is correct.

Please check it out.

Comment: Looks pretty solid. Note that $\langle a \rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}$ (as an abelian group) so in essence you have shown (or could have used if already known to you) the fact that the intersection of all ideals in $\mathbb{Z}$ is the zero ideal.

Comment: Small nitpick : you have $K_n\in \mathcal{A}$, not $\subset$